# docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile for mysql php apache application

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run my application in a docker container. I am able to run my PHP application in a docker container but I want to add mysql in my application and restore my sql dump in my database. And I want my application code to be cloned by dockerfile and httpd configuration with dockerfile itself.

here is my docker file

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN     yum -y update \
    && yum --setopt=tsflags=nodocs -y install \
    gcc \
    httpd \
    mod_ssl \unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum/* \
    && yum clean all

RUN rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
RUN yum remove php-cli php-common
RUN yum -y install php55w \
               php55w-opcache \
               php55w-xml \
               php55w-mcrypt \
               php55w-gd \
               php55w-devel \
               php55w-mysqlnd \
               php55w-intl \
               php55w-mbstring \
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git clone 
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@gitlab.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/Product/yyyyyyyyyyy.git 
abc;
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
RUN yum clean all
EXPOSE  80
#ADD ./abc/ /var/www/html/
COPY /abc/abclive/gitlab.abc/dev/  /var/www/html/
#WORKDIR  /var/www/html/abc/abclive/gitlab.abc/dev/
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT  /var/www/html/abc/abclive/gitlab.abc/dev/
WORKDIR  /var/www/html/abc/abclive/gitlab.abc/dev/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'
  services:
    web:
     build: .
       ports:
       - "8090:80"
          centos:
           image: "centos:centos7"
                #  links:
               #    - db
                #  volumes:
                 #    - .:/newvolebs
                  #db:
              #  image: "mysql:5.6"
               #  volumes:
                    #    - newvolebs:/var/lib/mysql/data
                   #  networks:
          #       - overlay
                 #  environment:
             #    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
              #    MYSQL_DATABASE: DATABASENAME
```

i have created one ebs volume attached it with my instance and make it usable with name "newvolebs"
how to mount it in my application database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with this dockerfile when i am using "docker-compose build" command  its stopped in copy command .with error no such directory.

Comment: docker `COPY` command can only be relative to the running directory. Not sure why you haven't used an existing apache/php image as a base.

Comment: i am new to docker my existing app is running on centos7 so i am using that here how can i resolve this.

Comment: when you build the docker image, the app has to be in the current directory or below. adjust config accordingly. If in doubt, read the [docker manual on copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: Basic improvements to language and formatting